# Jupyter Notebook not finding IQSharp

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, q#

I have been trying to get a Q# running for the Quantum Katas, but have been having some difficulty in finding the Q# kernal. The only kernal that shows up is the Python 3 one which is used for the Jupyter Notebook. The odd thing is that the kernal shows up when I do jupyter kernalspec list.I am using VS Code. 
[This is the jupyter kernelspec list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubk5J.png)

Comment: What happens if you add the “--user” flag to “dotnet iqsharp install”?

Comment: It says that it is not in the list of commands (flags), so nothing occurs.

Comment: That's strange, `dotnet iqsharp install --user` should definitely be supported. (You can run `dotnet iqsharp install --help` to see the list of supported flags.) Can you check that the iqsharp tool is correctly installed by running `dotnet iqsharp --version`? This should show you the installed version number. If it's not installed, try running `dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp` to install it, and then try `dotnet iqsharp install --user` again.

Comment: Actually, i just got it working in the jupyter notebook, but it is still giving me an error in VS Code. I updtaed my IQSharp to the latest version. Just a question, when you use the "Select a Kernel" option in VS Code, what path do I give it for the IQSharp. Currently, it is the python one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great, glad it's working in the Jupyter notebook! I'll add an answer here summarizing what I said above. As for VS Code, it looks like it doesn't currently support non-Python kernels for its Jupyter implementation. See this open issue:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8521

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing what was said in the comments above:

- First, make sure iqsharp is installed. Run `dotnet iqsharp --version` to ensure that the tool exists.

  - If not, run `dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp` to install it.
- Then run `dotnet iqsharp install` to register the IQ# kernel in your Jupyter configuration.

  - If your `jupyter` installation still doesn't recognize the kernel, it could be a permissions issue based on how you have installed and are running Jupyter. Try `dotnet iqsharp install --user` instead.

As for VS Code's Jupyter implementation, currently non-Python kernels such as R, Julia, Q#, etc. are not supported. This GitHub issue tracks adding support: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8521