# Install Quantum Development Kit (QDK) in Ubuntu, without conda

Tags: python, q#, qdk

I mean to use QDK in Ubuntu 22.04LTS.
I have a virtualenv, but no conda.
I installed qsharp in my venv with

```
$ pip3 install qsharp
```

but then

```
$ python -c "import qsharp"
IQ# is not installed.
Please follow the instructions at https://aka.ms/qdk-install/python.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

The link provided takes me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/install-overview-qdk?tabs=tabid-vscode%2Ctabid-conda.
The proper section is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/install-overview-qdk?tabs=tabid-vscode%2Ctabid-conda#use-q-and-python-with-jupyter-notebooks), where it is stated that I could use conda to install the necessary components for a Juptyer Notebooks environment.

I understand this could be the *easiest* way to do it.
But can I install a QDK precompiled package without conda?

**Related**:

1. https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-runtime
2. https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler
3. https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/issues/102
4. [Jupyter Notebook not finding IQSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62226431/jupyter-notebook-not-finding-iqsharp)
5. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/overview-what-is-qsharp-and-qdk

Comment: Did you read the message? It tells you what to do, did you try it?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy - Yes, I did, and that was the source of the question.
Nevertheless, I did not state it clearly in my OP. 
Now I have rewritten it.

Comment: I think the answer is no, they only distribute precompile package through conda channels. However you can go on their github page and they explain how to build it from source.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated on the [link](https://aka.ms/qdk-install/python) you provided, you requires to manually IQ# if you don't use conda (where it is done by installing the microsoft package)

so you need to run

```
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp
dotnet iqsharp install
```

`dotnet` can be downloaded here [from here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)

Comment: I had already done this. I will update my question.